# How to simply get the master volume of Windows in Python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a simple way to get windows' master volume in Python. Preferably a function that simply returns the master volume.

Something like this:

```
GetMasterVolume()
#0.3
```

Comment: What is a "master volume"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, use [pycaw](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw):

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
    IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))

volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar()
```