# How can i get the current sound level from my device?

Tags: python, audio, volume

I need to get the sound level of my pc, but there aren't any libraries that can do that!

Well i looked for libraries but there are none! So please help me

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simply get the master volume of Windows in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244635/how-to-simply-get-the-master-volume-of-windows-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pycaw` for Windows.

```py
round(volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar()*100)
```

This will return the volume in percentage.

https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The `pycaw` library is a good option for this.

You can view `pycaw`'s GitHub Examples [here](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/tree/develop/examples) for some code examples on how to use this library.

Note that this is only available on Windows devices.